# odd issue displaying javascript using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an odd issue with the JavaScript code I wrote. I am currently up to 1009 lines of code, so I would love to know where to start to fix this issue.

I am using `getelementid` to display to HTML from an external JS file, then using CSS to animate the JS client side.

```
display("<p>Welcome to TextHacker, a text based hacking simulation game</p>");
```

the code works but it only prints out up "Welcome to TextHacker, a text based hacking simulat" then stops in the browser. I have the same issue in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Valadi, so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is the CSS code:

```
p {
  color: lime; 
  font-family: "Courier";
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30em;
  animation: type 4s steps(60, end); 
}

p:nth-child(2){
  animation: type2 8s steps(60, end);
}

p a {
  color: lime;
  text-decoration: none;
}

span{
  animation: blink 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes type { 
  from { width: 0; } 
} 

@keyframes type2 {
  0%{width: 0;}
  50%{width: 0;}
  100%{ width: 100; } 
} 

   @keyframes blink {
    to{opacity: .0;}
   }

   ::selection {
     background: black;
    }
```

Comment: The code for `display()` is probably important here. A working example we can see would probably be useful, too.

Comment: you have `width: 30em; overflow: hidden` for `p` - that will cause any content wider than `30em` in a `p` to be `hidden`...

Answer (score 0):

Your width is cutting off the text.

```
p {
  width: 60em;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/08y8yknn/

Comment: this helped but then caused another issue when the code is ran it goes too far off the screen. i need to wrap the code after so far i tried "\n" but didn't have any effect

Comment: newlines aren't html.  You could use <br> or, rather, create an element that wraps your text.

Comment: when i use <br> it's on a new line it runs both lines of text at the same time. how could i create an element that wraps them